# BeautifulSoup - Finding children based on location of other child's parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, parent-child

I'm wanting to find data for a specific date using python, beautifulsoup, etc. The date in question, `IMPORTANT DATE`, is `Mar. 31, 2018` as seen below.

```html
<tr class="ro">
<td class="pl " style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_dei_DocumentPeriodEndDate', window );">IMPORTANT DATE</a></td>
<td class="text">Mar. 31,  2018<span></span>
</td>
<td class="text">&#160;<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using the following line of code to identify the `IMPORTANT DATE`.

```
for item in soup.find('td', text='Document Period End Date').parent.find_all('td', {'class':['text']}):
    if len(item.text.strip()) > 0:
        report_date = [item.text.strip()]
        print(report_date)
```

Note the use of `if len(item...)`. This is a hacky way of getting rid of the `&#160` but it works. Any better suggestion here is appreciated but not the main focus of my question.... moving on to that.

My main question is that if we identified that the location of the `IMPORTANT DATE` child is #1 (see below), how can we then go about getting the first child of some elements down the way (same grandparent)? See below.

```html
<tr>
<th class="tl" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><div style="width: 200px;"><strong>Condensed Consolidated Balance Sheets - USD ($)<br> $ in Thousands</strong></div></th>
<th class="th"><div>Mar. 31, 2018</div></th> # <-IMPORTANT DATE, 1st 
<th class="th"><div>Dec. 31, 2017</div></th> # <-wrong date 
</tr>
<tr class="ro">
<td class="pl " style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_InventoryNet', window );">Inventories, net</a></td>
<td class="nump">76,579<span></span> # <- data for important date 
</td>
<td class="nump">92,376<span></span> # <- data from wrong date
</td>
</tr>
```

To throw a curveball, sometimes the location of the important data isn't the location of the `IMPORTANT DATE` due to what I assume are some header columns under their parent `<tr>` element. See below.

```html
<tr>
<th class="th" colspan="1">3 Months Ended</th>
<th class="th" colspan="1"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="th"><div>Mar. 31, 2018</div></th> #<- IMPORTANT DATE, 3rd
<th class="th"><div>Dec. 31, 2017</div></th>
<tr class="ro">
<td class="pl " style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_LongTermDebt', window );">Long-term debt</a></td>
<td class="nump">data for important date<span></span> #<- important data is 1st
</td>
<td class="nump">unimportant data<span></span>
</td>
```

What I've planned to do was 1) create a reference to our `IMPORTANT DATE` in python, `report_date` with which to 2) compare the dates of our important data to our `IMPORTANT DATE` to finally 3) return that important data. However, somewhere between 1) and 2) my code breaks down because when trying the following lines:

```
for item in soup.select('filename:contains("' + filename + '")'):
    for item in soup.find('td', text='Document Period End Date').parent.find_all('td', {'class':['text']}):
        if len(item.text.strip()) > 0:
            report_date = [item.text.strip()]
    for th in item.find_all('th', text=report_date):
```

I know that at some point the css_selector `soup.select("p > a:nth-of-type(2)")` will come in handy but I haven't gotten to that step yet; I appear to be fairly well stuck.

Can anyone lend a hand here?

[soup can be found here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1524741/0001628280-18-004959.txt)

Comment: Is `IMPORTANT DATE` always the first date that occurs in the HTML snippets? It seems that in all the examples above, your desired date can be before before any others that appear later on in the HTML.

Comment: Not necessarily. The IMPORTANT DATE is found from a separate line of code further up in the soup. From there I wanted to use that date as a reference.

Comment: Seems, in small example above, that required data is always first table match on class name nump. So, select_one('.nump').text with ideally a table css selector in front of the class to ensure you have right table e.g. #tableId .nump

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last two elements (`<td>` or `<th>`) from row (`<tr>`) by doing `tr.select('td, th')[-2:]`. That way you will always ignore that optional first header column. Then you can do `zip()` function to connect the data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

case_1 = '''<table><tr>
<th class="th" colspan="1">3 Months Ended</th>
<th class="th" colspan="1"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="th"><div>Mar. 31, 2018</div></th>
<th class="th"><div>Dec. 31, 2017</div></th>
<tr class="ro">
<td class="pl " style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_LongTermDebt', window );">Long-term debt</a></td>
<td class="nump">data for important date<span></span> #<- important data is 1st
</td>
<td class="nump">unimportant data<span></span>
</td>
'''

case_2 = '''
<table>
<tr>
<th class="tl" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><div style="width: 200px;"><strong>Condensed Consolidated Balance Sheets - USD ($)<br> $ in Thousands</strong></div></th>
<th class="th"><div>Mar. 31, 2018</div></th>
<th class="th"><div>Dec. 31, 2017</div></th>
</tr>
<tr class="ro">
<td class="pl " style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_InventoryNet', window );">Inventories, net</a></td>
<td class="nump">76,579<span></span>
</td>
<td class="nump">92,376<span></span>
</td>
</tr>'''

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(case_1, 'lxml')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(case_2, 'lxml')

def get_data(soup):
    return [[row_data.text.strip() for row_data in tr.select('td, th')[-2:]] for tr in soup.select('tr')[-2:]]

print('Case 1:')
for i, (date, data_for_date) in enumerate(zip(*get_data(soup1)), 1):
    print('{}.\t{} - {}'.format(i, date, data_for_date))

print('\nCase 2:')
for i, (date, data_for_date) in enumerate(zip(*get_data(soup2)), 1):
    print('{}.\t{} - {}'.format(i, date, data_for_date))
```

Prints:

```
Case 1:
1.  Mar. 31, 2018 - data for important date #
2.  Dec. 31, 2017 - unimportant data

Case 2:
1.  Mar. 31, 2018 - 76,579
2.  Dec. 31, 2017 - 92,376
```

Comment: This method may not be as useful if the desired data is located in the 3rd or 4th row, etc. etc. for a different soup that'll need parsing. Methodology needs to be broad enough to work on different soups.